# How long has this character been impersonating a Starfleet Officer?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

I'm having trouble understanding when the changeover of characters occurred in *Star Trek Discovery* (I skipped some episodes).

> Did he (mirror captain Lorca) replace the real Lorca when the *Discovery* dropped out of the last spore jump in Episode 12 or did he swap places long before this episode?

Comment: This question could be answered by just watching the episodes you've skipped, and I imagine that would fall under the minimum prior research we expect here?

Comment: Why was this flagged as too broad? Voted to leave open.

Comment: @Jenayah Probably because "Question is explicitly answered in the Show" is not a VTC option.  Lorca *literally* tells Michael and the viewer where, **when** and how he swapped universes.

Comment: He has always been a Cylon.

Comment: Can we VTC for spoilers?   (...or at least do some editing?)

Comment: @AC No, we can't VTC for spoilers. Editing to add spoilertags is fair game though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "insufficiently researched" isn't an *expectation* as such. It's certainly a reason to downvote, but not to VTC.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Agreed!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

We never see the prime universe Lorca.

Lorca is introduced in "Context is for Kings" (episode 3). At this point, he's already light-sensitive. His first line is:

> LORCA: Forgive the lighting, or lack thereof. Recent battle injury. There's nothing they can do if I wanna keep my own eyes, and I do.

At the end of "Vaulting Ambition" (episode 12), Michael and Georgiou have this conversation:

> MICHAEL: You're sensitive to light.
>
> GEORGIOU: Only compared to a human from your universe. It's the singular biological difference between our two races.

and then Michael realizes that the Lorca she knows is the mirror universe version.

Since he's always been light-sensitive, he must have always been from the mirror universe.

Moreover, when he's talking to Michael in "What's Past is Prologue" (episode 13), he explicitly says:

> LORCA: I see you, Michael Burnham. I see your power. And I'm offering you a future. I have since the day I brought you onto the *Discovery*.

which only makes sense if he's been in command all along.

Comment: Also _he told us_ in  "What's Past Is Prologue"

Comment: Note also that the alleged battle injury was a total destruction of Lorca's ship; which he _appears to have survived beyond all expectations_. It's most likely that the real Lorca died there, and the alternate Lorca used it to assume the real Lorca's identity.

Comment: Which is such a shame.  Lorca was the best new Star Trek captain since Picard.